# Display ascii text (codes) in pre code tags?

Tags: php, html

Is there a way to display the ascii code ("`&#233;`" for "é", and not display "é" but "`&#233;`") in html using pre code? The only way I could find was to use a text/plain header header in PHP but then I would lose all possible styling. Why? because I have to work on a doc where people have to paste some ascii codes so I would need to be able to style and still display code and not render them.

Comment: Numeric character references use unicode, not ASCII.

Comment: One method you could use it to change the & to &amp; i.e. &#233 becomes &amp;#233

Comment: jeff, that works :) thanks a bunch! If you wanna make an answer, I'll validate it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function will convert characters with special meaning in HTML (like `&`) to their character references so that they will be displayed instead of having their special meaning.

Comment: Then it's rendered  in html unless I use a plain text header

Comment: @Eric — Umm. No. (Well, technically yes, but not in the way you mean).

Comment: @Eric — "jeff, that works :) thanks a bunch – Eric just now" — So this **does** work then.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the answer. If you use htmlspecialchars("&#233;") you would see &#233; not the symbol because the special characters that denote special characters are changed.

Comment: I don't understand why this received a downvote; it works.

Comment: Yes sorry my mistake

Comment: @Eric : Care to retract the DV then

Comment: Can't unless Quentin edits his answer for some reason

Comment: @Eric I did that for him ;-) edit: Ok, the same was done now.

Comment: @Shafizadeh — If you have comments about my answer to your question then comment on that answer. Don't delete your question and then ask about it on an unrelated answer.

Comment: @Quentin You are right ..! But I deleted my answer because it got 2 downvote ..! anyway I just wanted to show that fiddle to you.